# How to copy file from internet to local drive using xsl (file:copy)

Tags: xslt, copy

I would like to copy 3 files from an internet address to my local drive using xsl.

I don't have a choice re: using xsl - that is what I have to use - not my call.

I've found the [`file:copy`](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.copy) function from expath.org but I can't figure out the syntax.

Could someone post a simple example that works? I'm sure once I see what the function wants from me re: `$source` and `$target` etc. I'll be fine.

Comment: Are you at least using an XSLT processor supporting that function and having access to the local file system? And what kind of files are that? You need XSLT 2 at least any way to create several result documents with `xsl:result-document` and as long as you have XML or text files you can simply "write" them out using e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="foo.xml"><xsl:copy-of select="doc('http://example.com/foo.xml')"/></xsl:result-document>`, assuming you run your XSLT 2/3 processor locally.

Comment: I believe I am. I'm using Saxon and calling the xls from a bash script. I can copy the files no problem using the bash script but have to do it using xls.  

They are 3 largish (approx 5mb each) text files.

Here's how I'm calling the xls from bash:  

java -jar saxon9he.jar -s:example.xsl -xsl:example.xsl -o:example.txt

Comment: As far as I understand the `file:copy` function allows you to copy files that already exist on the local file system. And whether Saxon supports that module depends on the edition you have, I don't think the open-source HE supports that module. As for copying text files, I think what I outlined in a previous comment using `xsl:result-document`, only then with `<xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text"><xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text('http://example.com/foo.txt')"/></xsl:result-document>` would work. Where does the XSLT get the URL(s) of the files from, with an `xsl:param`?

Comment: thanks for the tip re: Saxon version - I didn't architect this system, I've been tasked with doing this little report (not for $$)  can I just put the urls in the command vs using a variable for them? they are static

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write a single XSLT 3.0 stylesheet (needs to be run with Saxon 9.8 and command line options `-it -xsl:sheet.xsl` (you can add `-t` for debugging to see where Saxon writes to)) downloading three hard-coded URLs you would e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="url1" as="xs:string?" select="'http://example.com/file1.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="url2" as="xs:string?" select="'http://example.com/file2.txt'"/>
    <xsl:param name="url3" as="xs:string?" select="'http://example.com/file2.txt'"/>


    <xsl:param name="source-urls" as="xs:string*" select="$url1, $url2, $url3"/>

    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <xsl:for-each select="$source-urls">
            <xsl:variable name="file-name" select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>
            <xsl:message select="'Writing ', ., ' to ', $file-name"/>
            <xsl:result-document href="{$file-name}" method="text"><xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(.)"/></xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that `unparsed-text` might need a second encoding parameter to be able to read the remote file properly (defaults to UTF-8 if not known or readable) and that `xsl:result-document` writes it out UTF-8 encoded by default I think, you can change it with an `encoding` attribute. Of course that all is no plain copying like the `file:copy`.

Comment: thanks - I must be doing something ridiculously wrong - when I paste that into a new xsl file and change the urls to point at what I'm trying to download then run it from a bash script using saxon nothing happens

Comment: Needs to be run with no source but with `-it` command line option.

Answer (score 0):

Extension functions in Saxon, including the EXPath file module, require Saxon-PE and a commercial license.

The EXPath `file:copy()` function can copy a file from one location to another, but both must be accessible by filename. It therefore can't be used directly to copy a resource that's addressed by URL and retrieved from the internet.

If the resource is XML, I would use the `document()` function to read it and the `xsl:result-document` instruction to write it.

If the resource is unparsed text I would use the `unparsed-text()` function to read it and `file:write()` to write it.

If the resource is binary (and accessed by HTTP) then I'm not sure there's an off-the-shelf way of reading it in Saxon, although it's easy enough to create a custom extension function for the job.

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the form of comments on an answer to a different question. Ask this as a new question please.